# Help me real analysis

Tags: real-analysis

I have to study character of this serie
$\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} (\log(n+1)-\log(n-1))$.
I know that it diverges but I don’t know how I have to show it

Comment: Compute the partial sums up to, say, $10$?

Comment: The series is asymptotic to $n^r$; determine $r$

Comment: I don’t understand

Answer (score 2):

The behavior of the series is determined by the growth of the partial sums. In this case you have a telescoping series, which means that due to a large amount of cancellation the partial sums have a particularly simple expression. The partial sum up to $n$ gives
$$
(\log 4-\log 2)+(\log 5-\log 3)+(\log 6-\log 4)+\cdots +(\log (n+1)-\log (n-1)).
$$
Note the $\log 4$ cancels with the $\log 4$ coming two terms later, and similarly for $\log 5, \ldots,\log (n-1)$. Consequently the partial sum equals
$$
\log(n+1)+\log n-\log 2-\log 3.
$$
As $n\to\infty$ this grows logarithmically, so the series diverges at a relatively slow rate (comparable to the harmonic series $\sum\frac{1}{n}$).

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} (\log(n+1)-\log(n-1)) = \sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \log{\frac{n+1}{n-1}} = \sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \log{\left(1+\frac{2}{n-1}\right)}$$

And remember that $\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}\rightarrow 1 $ for small $x$

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{n=3}^\infty (\log(n+1)-\log(n-1)) = \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=3}^N (\log(n+1)-\log(n-1)) = \lim_{N \to \infty} {({\sum_{k=4}^{N+1}\log k - \sum_{l=2}^{N-1} \log l})}$$

Can you complete the proof now?